# XF-Material-Library: How to open multiple dialogs

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use this library https://github.com/Baseflow/XF-Material-Library.

example:
I open the first dialog with a custom view I have a button in it which opens the second input dialog. Unfortunately, the second dialog with the input field does not open.

open dialog 1:

```
var dialog1 = await MaterialDialog.Instance.ShowCustomContentAsync(new ViewDialog1(), message:"Dialog1");
```

button in dialog 1 which opens dialog 2

```
var dialog2 = await MaterialDialog.Instance.ShowCustomContentAsync(new ViewDialog2(), message:"Dialog2");
```

I'd love for you to advise me on how to open more dialogues.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you need to close dialog1 before you open dialog2?

Comment: Just that I don't need to close the previous dialogue. I need to open another dialog box with my own content.